# Conjecture: $\frac1\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left((n+1)\frac{C_n^3}{2^{6n}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}{\frac{(n-k)(k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, generating-functions, pi, catalan-numbers

Let $C_n$ denote the $n$-th Catalan  number defined by

$${\displaystyle C_{n}={\frac {1}{n+1}}{2n \choose n}=\prod \limits _{k=2}^{n}{\frac {n+k}{k}}\quad \left(n\geqslant 0\right).}$$
Next, we define the sequence
$${\displaystyle A_{n}={\frac {C_{n}^{3}}{2^{6n}}}\sum _{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}{n \choose k}{\frac {(n-k)(k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}}}.$$
I've numerically managed to verify that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{pi}
{\displaystyle \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(n+1)A_{n}={\frac {1}{\pi}}}.
\end{equation}
Is it possible to prove the relation in (\ref{pi})? If yes, then how could we go about it?

Also, is this series already known or studied in the literature? If yes, then any references will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How did you come up with this identity?

Comment: @KentaS Experimental Mathematics?

Comment: $A_n$ simplifies to $C_n^2/4^{2n+1}$, and the partial summation $\sum_{n=0}^k (n+1)A_n$ then simplifies to $\frac{k+1}{16^{k+1}}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}^2$, so the problem reduces to limit

Comment: @Sil Oh I see, any idea if this series is already known in the literature?

Comment: @Permutator I am not aware of any such literature (though I wouldn't know probably)

Comment: @Sil I see, no problem. Also, if possible, could you please provide a proof using your approach of limits? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

$$\sum _{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}{n \choose k}{\frac {(n-k)(k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (n+2)}{4 \,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
$$ A_{n}={\frac {C_{n}^{3}}{2^{6n}}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (n+2)}{4 \,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{4 \pi  \Gamma (n+2)^2}$$
$$(n+1)A_n=\frac{(n+1) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{4 \pi  \Gamma (n+2)^2}$$
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p(n+1)A_n=\frac 1 \pi \frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma (p+2)^2}$$ Now, Stirling approximation
$$\log \left(\frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma (p+2)^2}\right)=\log(p+1)+2\log \left(\Gamma \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)-2\log \left(\Gamma \left(p+{2}\right)\right)$$
$$\log \left(\frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma (p+2)^2}\right)=-\frac{1}{4 p}+\frac{1}{4 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

$$\frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma (p+2)^2}=1-\frac{1}{4 p}+\frac{9}{32 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

$$S_p=\frac 1 \pi \left(1-\frac{1}{4 p}+\frac{9}{32 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right) \right)$$

Answer (score 3):

> We show OP's identity has a representation
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^{2n+1}}\,\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^2=\frac{1}{\pi}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> OP is asking for references and actually this series is well known and has an interesting history. It was Ramanujan who sent a generalisation of (1) to Hardy. This generalised form can be written, given $q$ a positive integer as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S(q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^{2n}}\,\frac{1}{n+q}\binom{2n}{n}^{2}=\frac{4^{2q}}{\pi q^2\binom{2q}{q}^2}\sum_{j=0}^{q-1}\frac{\binom{2j}{j}^2}{4^{2j}}}
> \end{align*}
> Note, in (1) we consider the special case
> \begin{align*}
> S(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^{2n}}\,\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{2}=\frac{4}{\pi}
> \end{align*}
> A generalisation of $S(q)$ with a nice reference to the history of $S(q)$ can be found in *[A Certain Series Associated with Catalan’s Constant](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0232-2064&vol=21&iss=3&rank=17)* by V. S. Adamchik.

In order to show (1) we simplify OP's $A_n$ with elementary means. The following is valid for $n\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)(k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=(n+1)4^{n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)(k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)\left(\frac{3}{4}\,\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{4}\,\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)\\
> &=n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\,\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{4}\,\frac{1}{2k-1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{3n}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{n}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}\frac{1}{2k-1}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Now we calculate the left-hand sum of (3) following an approach from problem section, chapter 1 in *[Combinatorial Identities](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1972-78-04/S0002-9904-1972-12968-9/S0002-9904-1972-12968-9.pdf)* by J. Riordan. We derive a recurrence relation by calculating $f_n$ in two ways.

\begin{align*}
f_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}\\
&=f_{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}\tag{4.1}\\
\\
f_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(1-\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}-2\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{k}{2k+1}\\
&=\delta_{n,0}-2n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}\tag{4.2}
\end{align*}

We combine (4.1) and (4.2) and obtain for $n\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
f_0&=1\\
f_n&=\delta_{n,0}-2n\left(f_n-f_{n-1}\right)\\
(2n+1)f_n&=2nf_{n-1}+\delta_{n,0}\\
f_n&=\frac{2n}{2n+1}f_{n-1}=\cdots=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}f_0=\frac{(2n)!!(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!}\\
&=\frac{2^nn!2^nn!}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{4^n}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}
\end{align*}

It follows
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}
=\frac{4^n}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}}
\end{align*}

In the same way we can calculate the right-hand sum of (3.3) and obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{g_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k-1}=-4^n\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}}
\end{align*}

> Putting $f_n$ and $g_n$ in (3) we obtain after some simplifications
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)(k-1)}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}}\\
> &=\frac{3n}{4}f_{n-1}-\frac{n}{4}g_{n-1}\\
> &=\frac{3n}{4}\,\frac{4^{n-1}}{2n-1}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}^{-1}+\frac{n}{4}\,4^{n-1}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}^{-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(n+1)4^{n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}=4^{n-1}C_{n}^{-1}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (2) follows.

With (5) we calculate $A_n$ as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A_n}&=\frac{C_n^3}{2^{6n}}4^{n-1}(n+1)C_n^{-1}=\frac{C_n^2}{4^{2n+1}}(n+1)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4^{2n+1}}\,\frac{1}{(n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}^2}
\end{align*}

> so that OPs identity can be stated as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^{2n+1}}\,\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^2=\frac{1}{\pi}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

Comment: More generally,$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac { {2\,n\choose n} ^{2}{z}^{
n}}{n+1}}={\frac {1}{4\,z\pi} \left( {\rm K} \left( 4\,\sqrt {
z} \right)  \left( -1+16\,z \right) +{\rm E} \left( 4\,\sqrt {
z} \right)  \right) }
$$is an elliptic integral.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks again for your hint. It stimulated me to do some further research and I found some nice details. I've added them in my post.